# Ironclad import error

Tags: ironpython, ironclad

I am getting the following error when trying to import a C-Extension I need with irconclad. Is this related to my configuration or limitation in ironclad?

```
C:\devtools\ipython>ipy
IronPython 2.0 (2.0.0.0) on .NET 2.0.50727.3053
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ironclad
>>> ironclad.__version__
'0.8.1'
>>> import acm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 15, in load_module
  File "ironclad", line unknown, in LoadModule
  File "ironclad", line unknown, in Load
  File "ironclad", line unknown, in Invoke
  File "ironclad", line unknown, in Py_IsInitialized
NotImplementedError: called Py_IsInitialized -- stack is probably corrupt now
```

Answer (score 1):

Ironclad is still a work in progress - it doesn't support every function in the Python C API yet. The developers are adding new ones as they encounter them when trying to get specific extension modules working.

The message looks alarming, but I don't think the stack corruption it mentions is accurate any more - it's a holdover from the early days of the project. I think the Py_IsInitialized function has been implemented in svn now, so you could try bugging them to make a new release. (I don't know the acm module - it's possible it uses other functions that also aren't implemented yet.)

You can probably get more help from the [Ironclad discussion group](http://groups.google.com/group/c-extensions-for-ironpython). I don't think the Ironclad developers read Stack Overflow, and they wouldn't be expecting to see Ironclad questions here (although it's a good sign!).